# How to remove validationError from the model in store?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I made an error while updating the model, and the model now has validation errors in the `validationError` model property.

But even I fetch the collection again and got new data for the model, the model's `validationError` is not gone in store.

So in list view, the collection length shows 0. Even if it has one, I confirmed it in store.

How can I remove the `validationError` on the model when I fetch the collection?

Comment: If there is a validation error, how did you update the model? I thought validation errors will reject the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Dealing with invalid data

If the data was stored within the database with an invalid state, you can either:

- Fix it **manually from the server** side with tools (like MySQL Workbench, etc.)
- Ensure **dynamically in the backend** that the data is valid before sending the response
- Make a **[`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) function in your Backbone Model** which handle the case you have right now

A simple parse function could look like:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  /**
   * Called with the raw response data
   */
  parse: function(data, options) {
    // fix the problem within the data object.
    if (_.has(data, 'myAttribute')) {
      data.myAttribute = /* correction here */
    }
    // return the fixed data object
    return data;
  }
});
```

## Why the collection length is zero?

It's because the collection sends the received data (locally as a param or following a fetch) to its [private `_prepareModel` method](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/539c9afad9c0af986704b26ea55ab62336c64fa2/backbone.js#L1186-L1197) which ensure that the data is a valid Backbone Model.

> ```
> _prepareModel: function(attrs, options) {
>   if (this._isModel(attrs)) {
>     if (!attrs.collection) attrs.collection = this;
>     return attrs;
>   }
>   options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};
>   options.collection = this;
>   var model = new this.model(attrs, options);
>   if (!model.validationError) return model;
>   this.trigger('invalid', this, model.validationError, options);
>   return false;
> },
> ```

It returns the model only if `validationError` is *falsy* (`null` by default and *thruty* whenever a validation rule returned an error message string or array).

```
if (!model.validationError) return model;
```

Otherwise, it returns false and doesn't add the model to the collection.